# Do ISP’s in America keep IP assignment logs forever?

Tags: network, logging, dhcp

1. I read that the majority of ISP’s keep theirs for at least 180 days. However, does anyone know how long charter spectrum keeps theirs?
2. Do ISP’s retain their logs forever even if they are using a DHCP protocol?
3. And why do some major ISP’s delete their logs at all? Is it to save on money or do they not want to be held liable?

Comment: If you never throw backups away it means you continuously have to buy more storage *and hire more people* to handle the continuously increasing amount of data. At a certain point most of your resources will be used for handling the backups (actually you will stop before when those costs will reduce the earning margin to 0). So money is surely a good reason.

Comment: This question suffers the same problems as your last. How long a particular company keeps their logs is up to them. You will have to contact their support. You also appear to assume that ISPs should keep IP assignment logs forever and you are wondering why they do not. Perhaps that's the better, and more general, question to ask and an assumption to explore.

Comment: Schroeder hackney answered what I wanted FINALLY. I knew someone else would know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Residential service IPs are often rotated so logs are instrumental in matching a time of use with a person.  There seems to be no legislation on how long logs need to be kept and most providers keep IP logs for 6-18 months.  None keep them forever as it is a liability and takes effort to do that beyond what's useful.  It is both about saving internal operational costs and having to cooperate with law enforcement.
Spectrum is Charter Communications.  In December 2017 information published on the Charter website indicated they keep 12 months of logs, however this information is no longer available on the Spectrum site.  Spectrum site IP information request page does not indicate how long logs are kept.
https://www.spectrum.com/policies/lea.html